# Different screenshots decorated with almost same words!

Tags: discussion, moderation, plagiarism

How to deal with this special kind of plagiarism?

1) Original (most probably): [Invalid Pointer Operation - Delphi XE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113097/invalid-pointer-operation-delphi-xe)

2) Plagiarism (most likely): [EInvalidPointer message with 'Invalid Pointer Operation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397182/einvalidpointer-message-with-invalid-pointer-operation)

The text seems to be **first class plagiarism** with **obscuring modifications**. But maybe the intent isn't that bad: many SO users are not native English speakers, so one can understand that, besides Google, this kind of "help" is used. These 3 sequences match exactly:

> program compiles and runs successfully, but during debugging only it pops up a message box saying "Invalid Pointer Operation" when shutting the program down.
>
> I found none and they execute as expected without any error.
>
> When I do tell the compiler to break at Invalid Pointer Operation error, it doesn't do anything but hangs up the program.

**Making a screenshot** does not need special language skills, the one in the second question seems to be made by the asker.

I already flagged the question, but there are no visible reactions so far...

What do you think?

Comment: The window styles differ and one screenshot has a checkbox checked while the other one hasn't.. It is a standard error message, why would they need to plagiarise that at all?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, a misunderstanding, the **plagiarism is in the text**. I should probably better quote it.

Comment: Right, the questions do seem closely related.

Comment: @KevinBrown: the question body text is *awfully* close, but altered sufficiently with a *new* screenshot to not be obvious at first.

Comment: Yep, the question text seems to be badly copied...

Comment: Are there other posts from the second user that fit this pattern? The question is rather old, the damage was done and a good answer was posted, so we cannot just go and delete this. It can certainly be dupe-voted, perhaps merged.

Comment: That's certainly strange, but I don't know if it's anything to be alarmed about  The newest question is almost two years old, and cursory search of their other questions doesn't turn up any automatic hits, although one of the [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881824/how-to-do-region-collapse-for-js-in-visual-studio-2012-2013) *was* copied by [another site](http://exchange.opcartstore.com/questions/view/7322/how-to-do-region-collapse-for-js-in-visual-studio-2012-2013?order=newest&page=1).  It's always funny what questions like these turn up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had a look on some of them, not systematically. I found nothing so far. Interestingly the plagiarism is a relatively late question :-/

Comment: I feel like, at several years removed, there's nothing we can or even should do about this.

Comment: How can you plagiarise a question? If anything, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ: Plagiarism is defined as copying someone else's work and passing it off as your own. It can apply to any type of written work. It may sound strange to "plagiarise" a question, so I prefer to think of it as parroting someone else's words and pretending you said them yourself. Which is equally mind-boggling.

Comment: @Wolf: Just curious, but how did you even find this in the first place?

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ How can you plagiarise a comment? If anything, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @musefan very interesting answer: the SE software itself listed the first question as related to the second :-)

Comment: This has got to be the most intriguing case of plagiarism I have ever seen.

Comment: @Wolf: Ah that makes sense, I rarely pay attention to that section myself and most of the time forget it even exists :/

Comment: @corsiKa This is kind of typical, if you expect that your "work" will be checked for plagiarism, you'll try to hide it by modifications. As we see, not very well done in this case.

Comment: @corsiKa: As a mod, I've seen 1) 100% plagiarized questions, no changes whatsoever, "EDIT:" portions included, with askers then responding to answers as though the questions were their own when it's pretty obvious from their writing style that they aren't 2) answers that are plagiarized with a few words changed here and there, like the case being described here 3) users with the **habit** of posting such answers, with some of the absolute worst plagiarism cases I've ever had the pleasure to deal with in my capacity.

Comment: I don't understand this at all, nor how this has over ten upvotes.  A question cannot be plagiarized--it can be duplicated.  If I ask this exact question again, word for word, it would be considered a duplicate and marked as such.  I'd probably be asked in a mod message what was going on, as it is very odd behavior.  Is this a language barrier thing?  Plagiarism implies a benefit to the perpetrator; no benefit here unless puppeting for points, and it doesn't seem likely. Anyhow, it seems extremely likely that two noobs could have hit the same error and posted very similar questions.

Comment: Why can a question not be plagiarized? It is posted content. If the text is verbatim then it is plagiarism, there is no grey area. Copied content without attribution is plagiarism. Period. End of statement. **the practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own**. A question is essentially a reproduction of work with a dilemma or quandary. With the phrasing it seems almost entirely unlikely that any two different people would compose that sentence.

Comment: It's clear that the latter question copied the former, since the sentence that begins "I found none" makes sense in the first question, but is a complete non sequitur in the second, due to the sentence just before it having been omitted.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @Toby Allen: Because plagiarism is wrong...? And on top of that, you really shouldn't be duplicating entire questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's been quite a while since this took place, so there's not much that can be done except merging the newer question into the older one and scratching our heads puzzled as to what must have gone through the mind of that user to have thought copying the overall presentation, as well as a few phrases and sentences verbatim, was a perfectly sound thing to do.

At the very least, merging will result in the newer question becoming nothing more than a stub, with all its answers being transferred to the older question.

Usually, if you catch someone doing something like this, you can vote to close it as a duplicate immediately if you have the original link, and ask the user why they did that. I'd like to know why people do this as well.

Comment: `I'd like to know why people do this as well.` for a question on SO, a screenshot alone is not sufficient, but if decorated with some words, it will be accepted. But writing is hard work. (Illustrations are great eye-catchers.)

Comment: @Wolf: But even though it's a screenshot of what I presume is their own program, **it's the same error message**. I mean, surely that's how they discovered the original question, right?

Comment: [Now](http://www.pceworld.com/view/14397182) it seems even more unclear, who was plagiarizing.

Comment: @Wolf: That site, like many others, rehosts content off of Stack Overflow. It does link back to the original and acknowledge the content license though, so it's not stealing.

Comment: I see. Many sites. Sometimes it's obvious, sometimes it's not. It can be really confusing at first glance.

Comment: I believe it is most likely that these people were following the same tutorial / book / example when they got the error.

Comment: @Grant: Even so I still can't fathom what compels them to create questions that are nearly identical except for a few changed words. It's not like the book provides a sample question to post on Stack Overflow that they then copy off of or something, is it?

Comment: @BoltClock You got me in stitches with the image of a book providing a sample question to post on Stack Overflow. I can't explain that either, but I asked the questioner to explain with a link to this thread so hopefully he or she will be so kind to resolve this mystery.

Comment: @Grant No, it's not just two people who happened to get the same error. Look at the phrase "I found none" in each question. In one question, it refers to checking for errors, mentioned in the previous sentence. In the other question, the bit about checking for those errors has been omitted, and so "I found none" becomes a complete non sequitur.

Comment: I would guess the OP copied the sentences as help in his use of the English language. When you look at others questions of this user, you can see that his English is not particularly good (but not terribly bad either), so I guess he saw the first question and had the same /very similar problem and posted his questions with the copied sentences with the intention to have use correct English.

Comment: @dirkk: That has been the only plausible explanation so far, along with cultural influences. Unfortunately academics see it as plagiarism which, regardless of intentions, is considered wrong. We try to take a more diplomatic approach when speaking to users who habitually engage in this behavior, but it's a little disheartening we have to do so at all. (And I'm honestly not sure they'll even understand what we tell them...)

Comment: @BoltClock is there another English term besides *plagiarism* for the product of plagiarism (the copy itself) in the non-academic scope, that is more commonly used, maybe *verbatim copy* or *rip-off*?