# What does Stack Overflow mean by plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I have seen [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299777/what-should-be-done-with-users-found-guilty-of-plagiarism), and it really caught my interest. How does one plagiarise someone's work on SO?

I mean, if the question was posted here and a solution was found, why would one ask it again? I just didn't get it.

About the code posted on SO, I thought people just posted examples; I would not post any of my work code here simply because work ethics and the idea of trying it first. I would have to debug first, then if that doesn't work take that section of the code tweak it, since I understand my code, and see if I can maybe get help. But overall I just needed to know what it means.

Comment: Did your major have rules relating to plagiarism? It's the same basic principle: don't pass off someone else's work as your own. Why would someone plagiarize a question if they *weren't* trying to cheat the system? [I have no idea either.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283375/different-screenshots-decorated-with-almost-same-words/283379#283379)

Comment: in this you mean they take up the code and change it or what really happens for it to be posted here?

Comment: we had rules but in mathematics its different you can tell when someone actually did plagiarism.. by simply looking and comparing at how he/she ended up with the final result... but in coding i admit i am confused. Why would one ask a question knowing well he picked it up somewhere? still confused by this. the answer given above has not answered my question.. but my question is closed. Maybe do you have an example i can look at?

Comment: In the case of Internet postings you can often see this in the writing style. If someone who isn't a native English speaker is suddenly posting well-written posts there is a high chance they didn't actually write the posts themselves. In many cases, you can also tell if something looks suspicious if it is missing some context or if some sentences/paragraphs are broken, for example if an answer starts right off with "The code we just looked at in Figure 10-1..." As for questions, yeah it confuses me too. The human condition boggles the mind.

Comment: @BoltClock Most of the plagiarism that I see on SO are lame attempts to farm rep or get out of bans. I'm sure you see a lot more possibly for other reasons as well.

Comment: *"Why would one ask a question knowing well he picked it up somewhere?"* - I can only think either: 1. the question hadn't been answered, or not answered to their satisfaction, but they wanted an answer and thought that asking it again verbatim would be the easiest way to get eyes on it (particularly if their own writing skills are poor); or 2. the question had a bunch of up-votes and they thought it would be an easy way to get rep (assuming nobody noticed it was a copy).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I remember the half-dozen or so attempts at riding on the branch-prediction question that I could smell from miles away...

Comment: @BoltClock I am often tempted to slip pictures of trains into my answers, but a good opportunity comes up so infrequently!

Comment: Well is it okay to say then that it is not clear what plagiarism is when it comes to the site and the coding world? maybe stack overflow should advice people not to post their work entirely so as to avoid this, now in math unless the one who stole it knows it very well its easy to spot plagiarism -- reasons being he/she wont be able to know how whoever did it came up with that step... in the coding world. i'm confused because take this example-- i see a code in java and decide to do it in C, is that plagiarism?

Comment: (Is it considered plagiarism on StackOverflow.com to take material from another answer on the same question and re-use it with modifications?) what if i use it in C or C++ if it was done in Java?

Comment: *"is it okay to say then that it is not clear what plagiarism is when it comes to the site"* - no, it is perfectly clear what counts as plagiarism (that doesn't make it easy to *detect* it, but that's a different matter...); the same as everywhere else, using someone else's work without attribution. All subscriber content on SE network sites, per the [TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal), is released under [CC BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which requires attribution (and broadly defines what form that should take).

Comment: okay my other arguments are in the coding world the reason as to why i can not go write my own matlab or mathematica is because we already have them working and useful but say i have the capability to write my entire software which looks the same... will i be reported for  plagiarism.. I just need some guide. Another example i feel uneasy when i import classes  what if i want to write my own? definitely they will be a complete replica of the same class is this also  plagiarism?Note: the only difference would be the variable, class naming.

Comment: @MadonahSyombua what do you mean *"looks the same"*? There are various forms of protection for IP; for example, creating software that apes the UI of MATLAB would probably fall under [*"trade dress"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_dress) legislation (depending on jurisdiction, etc.). See also e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/32482/110531 - there's no one-size-fits-all answer, and your taking legal advice on the internet is as foolish as me giving it!

Comment: No, I know better not to look for legal advice from the internet, i was just trying to understand what SO means by  plagiarism... well this topic is broad and i see, SO might need to just post some guidelines on what  plagiarism is. :) looks the same meant performs the same function

Comment: @MadonahSyombua and *"i feel uneasy when i import classes"* - why? Where are you getting them from? You can always check the software's license (see e.g. https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.4.3/license/, which covers the standard library too, and projects from e.g. GitHub will generally have a `LICENSE` file).

Comment: Okay this is because i love knowing what was done for that function.. just my thing.. like in java when i say import some utils.. that's the idea. I don't know about python but C and C++ gives me the ability to create my own so not bad. I think its because what i learned dont concentrate on the answer but how i got there that is knowing all the steps. Thanks jonrsharpe

Comment: @BoltClock: "Did your major have rules relating to plagiarism?" The issue here is that stackoverflow has this "everyone can edit your answer/question" thing. In conjunction with that, talk about plagiarism is baffling, especially when it happens within site (copy-pasting content from posts made by others on SO).  So it would make sense if site cared about attribution (original author should always be mentioned) OR information (only information matters, not its source), not both of them at once.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Simple: plagiarism is posting someone else's words (code, prose) without making it clear that you *are* posting someone else's words. Note that this has *nothing* to do with copyright or any other legal concept; it is a matter of showing respect for the work of your fellow authors. If you're ever in doubt about whether attribution is *necessary*, then include it - it never hurts to show respect, and often hurts to withhold it.

Plagiarism is easy to avoid, and for most people it is a second nature; you generally wouldn't write an email to your co-worker by pasting together paragraphs from other emails you'd seen, and so you wouldn't post such an abomination on the Internet either.

But... It does happen. And a handful of users make such posts the bulk of their contribution to the site. Reasons can include...

- Calculated attempts to garner upvotes by appropriating material that has already been well-received elsewhere.
- A near-complete inability to write legible English on their own.
- Education in a culture that values re-use over composition, but does not stress attribution.

For this reason, [we have put together a help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq) that lays out some useful guidelines for folks unfamiliar with normal practices for quoting and attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Authors who ignore these guidelines may find their posts deleted; those who repeatedly engage in this practice may find their accounts suspended or deleted.

Comment: Does this also include if i took the code modified it in another language eg from Java to C++? and asked a question if i had errors?

Comment: @MadonahSyombua: Sure a good idea, if you take some code and try to translate it into another language, you mention the source. It might or might not be required, that depends on the specifics. Like "Translated from someuserlink's C# codelink". In any case it also helps answer any question you might have, as the original presumably works and might have lots of important other information.

Comment: Probably not. Realistically, if I'm learning from someone's writing and writing about the concept *in my own words* then that's no longer plagiarism; that's... Normal writing. But if you're ever in doubt, it does not hurt to note where you learned something, @MadonahSyombua.

Comment: @MadonahSyombua ...and that's why you don't get legal advice on the internet!

Comment: A bit nit-picky but how does the center you mention help plagiarists originated in the second item (linguistic insufficiency)? And I'm also very curious if there are any actual examples of such cultures as referred to in the third item in the concurrent world. Or were you listing that for completeness' sake?

Comment: Not really, @Konrad - it provides a template to follow, but we've had decidedly mixed results. As for examples of cultures... I'd rather not say; it's been a real problem from some quarters (and on sites that draw from them), but I do believe most of it can be addressed with education (hence the help center article and an associated moderator message template).

Comment: @Shog9 side note:  while not plagiarism in the SO sense, using someone else's ideas, even though in not the same words without citing the original IS considered plagiarism.  It's not just "direct quotes" but also concepts.  Of course, in the code world, EVERYTHING is based on something already documented (e.g. the official site, etc) so it would, of course, be pointless.  <soapbox off/>