# Should I mark my answer as community wiki when I am posting in someone's name who does not have an account?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki, plagiarism

I shared a question with someone I know who has expertise in that field. They proposed a working solution, but do not want to open a Stack Overflow account. Instead they asked me to just post the solution since I'm a user here anyway. I feel that is wrong, because I did not actually come up with the solution, though I would be writing the actual answer (but not the code).

Besides writing "I am posting this for someone else" in the answer, which is really weird and I have never seen it done, I thought I could just mark it as community wiki. That way I will not take credit for someone else's work that cannot be quoted as it was just discussed by me and my friend, but the solution is accessible.

Is there a consensus amongst Stack Exchange users on how behave in a situation like that?

Comment: Just post it with proper attribution.

Comment: I'd post it as CW and also give attribution if friend is OK with that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- **Posting the answer in the first place**

  Since they gave you permission, I'd say you're fine on this front.

  Strictly speaking, however, there are some things to consider:

  - Does he own this content to begin with? Perhaps he recited it almost word-for-word from some resource which can't be shared on Stack Overflow without the author's explicit permission.
  - Does he know which licence it will be shared under? He may not be happy with the licencing Stack Overflow uses.

  Although you should probably ask yourself, in general, how likely someone is to take legal action here if you find yourself in the wrong - I'd say not very at all.
- **Giving credit**

  It really depends what he expects here.

  I don't think "I am posting this for someone else" is particularly useful (and I'd probably edit that out of a post if I see it). It should either be by name or nothing.
- **Making it Community Wiki**

  I would say this is optional. [The help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) doesn't refer to this, or a closely related, use case for it, and I don't believe there are really restrictions on making your posts Community Wiki when they don't need to be.

  If it was clearly essentially written by someone else (whether by your own admission or not), some people might expect it to be Community Wiki, and downvote if it's not, although, if posted in good faith, I don't expect downvotes to be common.

  So really it's up to you. If you don't feel you deserve the reputation, make it Community Wiki.

Answer (score 8):

IANAL

As per my view, as long as you're not stealing credit from another user *here*, I think you can post in directly from your account. No need for a community wiki there. Attribution, on the other hand is always welcome.

Just for clarification, I don't attribute each and every answer to the author of a book from which I might have read and gained the knowledge to answer the same.

Comment: This sounds like stealing from some other place is ok. I don't agree. The point is, there was a discussion (as in we talked to each other) and I have nothing to link to as the friend didn't want to write it down.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't attribute every book you've ever read that may have contributed to you knowing what you wrote in your answer, but it's a different story if you're copying something directly from a book - you don't automatically have legal rights to repost anything you wish (not to mention that not giving attribution is just not a nice thing to do). Although I'd say this is not close enough to what we're talking about here (posting an answer...).

Comment: @simbabque "stealing from some other place is ok"..no that is not ok. We're taking about the point on making it a community wiki. Attribution is always welcome. I updated my post for clarity.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, attribution is required and encouraged as a good and fair practice, but that does not imply every attributed answer should be community wiki, right? :)

Comment: Yep I agree.  You have to draw the line somewhere in terms of attributing your ideas and thinking models to your teachers, mentors etc.  Otherwise, almost your entire answer would be people in your life.  Attribution is for very specific instances of "this is not my idea, and I have not adapted it."

Comment: Hey now! Every time you tell someone to avoid a `goto` statement, you *have* to cite Dijkstra's *Go To Statement Considered Harmful*.

Answer (score 7):

Having been in this situation a couple of times from the other side, being the person who didn't want to create a Stack Overflow account, I can say you wouldn't be the first person to do this or that there's anything wrong with it.

As far as attribution goes, since there's no expectation here that the ideas in answers be original, [you only need to provide attribution if you're not using your own words](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299918). So if you're copying the other person's code into your answer then you would need attribute that contribution to the post. If the rest of the post is in your own words then you wouldn't need attribution for that part.

Note that even if the person who wrote the code included in your post wishes to be anonymous you should still give an anonymous attribution. For example: "The above code was provided for this answer by someone who I know who wishes to remain anonymous."

The choice of making the answer a community wiki is up to you, but I wouldn't bother. Since you went to the effort of writing up and posting the answer, as far as I'm concerned you deserve the points as much as anyone.

Comment: if they want to remain anonymous, is it ok to create a generic SO account, post it from that account, and provide them with the credentials should they ever decide they want to take the credit and/or join SO?

Comment: @Michael I don't think that would be appropriate. You shouldn't create an account for someone who doesn't want one, and I don't think the terms of service allow you to create an account for anyone other than yourself.

Comment: @RossRidge: The main problem is that **legally** you can't enter contracts on behalf of another (unless specifically arranged - power of attorney etc). An account gives you rights in exchange for obligations, which means it effectively is a contract. The ToS cannot alter this fundamental law. Would be rather nasty if you could: I'd sign a contract with my neighbor on behalf of you, and by the ToS of that contract you'd be obliged to give my neighbor $100.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** if you write a good answer, you absolutely deserve the reward, no matter how you found the solution (except copyright violations).

---

If it was an RPG, you would consider it a successfull check of speech skill.

Now, serious: you spent the time and effort to

1. find an expert,
2. ask them a good question,
3. understand the answer,
4. write a good post about it.

Writing about anything in a clear and understandable way is its own labor. So why can not you be rewarded with some reputation for the answer? How is it different from all other answerers, who know what they know from books, colleauges, teachers? I'm sure that they don't append a note, saying "by the way, I'd learned this trick from prof. Brown on my second year at the University of XYZ" to every answer.

**Almost everything we know, we know from somebody else.**

So, in my opinion, if you write a good answer, you absolutely deserve the reward.

What really matters (as stated by @Dukeling):

1. Is it a copyrighted knowledge or code?
2. Does the original author want to be mentioned in the answer. Maybe they want you to mention their name or give a website/blog/email, so that they can be contacted by future readers?

<sub>I'm not a native speaker; sorry for possible mistakes. Please fix them if you have time, I'll be most grateful.</sub>