# How to post answers while referring to external answers

Tags: discussion

My question is related to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109999/2664200) which was deleted by one of the moderators.

The OP's question was [how to check if a Date is greater than other in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109960/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-greater-than-other-in-java).

As I found one external answer which can clearly solve the OP's answer and as we are not allowed to post links as answers.

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

So I have copied the code from the source link and posted it as an answer. I have also given the source link in my answer.

My question:

1. What modifications should I do to make it visible to future users as it's deleted?
2. If in future, if I want to post code from external sites then how
   should I do that (https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing does not
   mention about showing code from external sites)?

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
>   another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all
>   of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

For the above answer I am not showing the author name, but I am showing the relevant codes and the source link.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134715/153008 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299915/what-does-stack-overflow-mean-by-plagiarism

Comment: Note that *code* is no different from *prose* here. Read 'words' to apply to 'code' just as much.

Comment: From just the title, I would be very surprised if that question isn't a duplicate... Oh, and it is! Why are you answering obvious duplicates?

Answer (score 13):

Do not copy and paste the contents of the link into your answer. **Use your own words** and, at most, quote relevant sections from linked resources. Links should only be there for additional information and background, they should not *be* the answer, and neither should you commit copyright breaches.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing:

> Do *not* copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.

If you can't answer in your own words, at most leave the link in a comment.  (and if you can't comment yet, gain enough reputation by other means so you *can* comment).

This applies to code just as much as to prose. If the point is to illustrate how to use a specific function or API, write your own code to demonstrate.

Comment: will it be ok if I modify the answer having my own codes? Though I have to use some of authors codes

Comment: @SpringLearner: sure! It if is a *technique* or specific function call or API, then write your own to show how to use that. Use links to support your argument (*see here for more examples, the author explains why FooBar is better here than BarBaz*).

Comment: As you said **Use your own words** ,its applicable if we want to show some texts but for codes what shall I do?

Comment: @SpringLearner: write your own code. Code is expression too. For 'words' read 'code' and the same applies.

Comment: Can you please tell me if it can be undeleted?

Comment: @SpringLearner: flag the answer for moderator attention once you've edited it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Will I get my deleted answers back if I edit them with my own words and still keep the pasted blog part? Cause I saw really how those copied answers helped others

Comment: @AlexJolig A car helps me get around, but that doesn't make it OK to steal one.

Comment: @philipxy It's not stealing when you credit the original author! It's helping people to find that blog easier I believe.

Comment: @AlexJolig: it is when that’s the only content in the answer. You are getting credit (reputation) for the words of others. Just because you put the name of the owner on a stolen car doesn’t mean that everyone else is okay with you driving it around.

Comment: @AlexJolig Stack Overflow is not about helping people find blog posts. Your posts can be undeleted when fixed but you need to be writing *original answers*, where a blog post is **at most** used to add support for your answer and as a further reference.

Comment: @AlexJolig for the majority of your posts I don’t see any reasons to give you back the reputation for having copied someone else’s work. If you are here to help people you can better write a new, original answer.

Comment: @AlexJolig However, I am repeating what I already said in my answer and in my comments to the OP on this answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, that was a long repetition. But Ok. I wouldn't repeat what I've done if you did it sooner. I didn't know about this role. Thanks for clearing things out.