# Using hyperlinks to external sites on SO

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

There seems to be some contention around using hyperlinks to external sites on SO.  I presume this is because links can eventually stop working.

Are there other reasons to not use hyperlinks?

If there is a large amount of reference information, what is the best way to reference it if hyperlinks are frowned upon?

Comment: that'd be a great answer, @Tiny... I'll bet there's a *hyperlink* to a past discussion you could include too if you wanted to flesh it out ;-)

Comment: Related: [How to post answers while referring to external answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341481/2675154)

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with a link, or even multiple links, in an answer, but the issue is: is the answer still a good answer when the links die? So, use externals links to back up your answer, show where you got information from, or provide further reading. Don't use external links to simply say "the answer is there".

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue with external links is that they die. All the posts on the site need to be self contained within the post on the site, so if a link does die, all the required information is still on the site.

There's nothing wrong with adding a link to give people an option for further reading or to give attribution when referencing other's work.