# When should answers consisting entirely of cited, copied content be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, plagiarism, legal

The Help Center article on [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says

> Do *not* copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And *always* give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, **including a direct link to it**.

I flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464531/208273) that appears to adhere to the second sentence (it includes a direct link and names the author), but does not appear to adhere to the first. Apart from the citation, the entire answer consists of a 250-line code block copied from the linked site (though it does not copy the *entire* linked article, it also adds nothing to it).  The flag was declined, stating:

> Why? It appears to provide the best attribution possible, within the constraints of the information that is available. I see no point in deleting this. Note that mods don't enforce legal licensing.

This isn't an unreasonable position to take, but it seems contrary to the help center and other answers from moderators on Meta that emphasize things like ["Use your own words"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341482/208273) and ["we expect answers on Stack Overflow to be original contributions by and large"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321326/208273), so I'm asking to clarify how I should handle these sorts of answers in the future:

**When, if ever, should answers consisting entirely of cited, copied content be flagged?**

Comment: When copying code, from a **cited** offsite resource, how would you propose that the user uses their own words instead? Name the objects something else? That sentence, in my opinion, doesn't apply to code, as you can't apply "your own words and ideas" to a copy of code. Citing the code, and copying it seems the best method. If, however, You were to then go on to explain the code (which a really good answer should), *then* you should be using your own words and/or quoting the relevant parts and explaining those in more detail.

Comment: I explicitly include the bit from the help center in my flags when there's even a shred of ambiguity to make it abundantly clear that there's a reason for the flag

Comment: @Larnu to quote [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341482/208273) from one of the linked answers, "This applies to code just as much as to prose. If the point is to illustrate how to use a specific function or API, write your own code to demonstrate."  Alternately, while still using the code from the blog, it could add to it by explaining how to use the code to solve the problem (the blog post elaborates on this, for instance).

Comment: As with our homework policy, this is another case of confusing guidance/recommendations offered on Meta sites with prohibitions/policy. We *strongly recommend* that users explain things in their own words and submit original content. However, we do not enforce that with deletion or other sanctions.

Comment: That's why I find licensing weird. You can copy large chunks of text/code from one site with an unknown licence into Stack Overflow with the CC BY-SA 4.0 licence and all that is fine because you also add the name? So it doesn't matter what licence the original text has? I find that weird.

Comment: @Tom Copying it does _not_ relicense it; that's why it's important that it be cited as originating off-site, so that it's clear that content is _not_ available under CC BY-SA.

Comment: We only enforce *our own site's* licensing, @Tom, not *other site's* licensing. The content provider is on their own honor to do that correctly and in compliance with all applicable restrictions. If you believe that they didn't, a DMCA copyright claim must be filed.

Comment: @CodyGray It is hard to tell what their licence is/was, because their own licence site doesn't work and even the wayback machine has no running version of it

Comment: That's correct. That's part of why we don't care and don't enforce other sites' policies, @Tom.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed)*

Comment: Similar: *[How much can be quoted before it is considered plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343641)*, *[When is using another poster's content plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389)* (internal to Stack Overflow), and *[Changes to discourage plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315)*.

Answer (score 7):

Only flag posts for copying content when they do so in violation of [our referencing/attribution policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). That basically just requires that the contributor undertook a good-faith effort to give credit to the original author, under a (very large) umbrella doctrine of "fair use".

It is very easy to properly reference material contributed to Stack Exchange sites, but it is sometimes more difficult to gather all the expected information when linking to a blog post or other off-site resource. For example, the referencing policy requires that one "provide the name of the original author". That becomes difficult if the author's name—or even an Internet "handle"—cannot be found anywhere on the page. However, that does not mean that the content cannot be posted here without violating our referencing policy. You just need to gather all of the information that you can reasonably find, keeping within the *spirit* of the policy.

As alluded to in the flag decline message, the primary concern that moderators police in regard to "copied content" flags is *plagiarism*, which is attempting to take credit for others' work. It is not our intention, and not within our purview, to enforce legal or licensing matters. We're not lawyers, and it's not within our interest (or that of the network at large) to attempt to do so.

Relevant to this is the network-wide [Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), specifically the section on "Copyright":

> **Copyright.** Using copyrighted material does not constitute infringement in all cases. In general, however, users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the permission of those who created it. It is our policy to respond to notices of alleged infringement sent to legal@stackoverflow.com that comply with the [Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA")](http://www.loc.gov/copyright/legislation/dmca.pdf).

The above-quoted text tells you how claims of copyright infringement are to be handled—by filing a formal [DMCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) claim. Moderators do not process these claims, as we cannot distinguish between genuine and fake copyright claims, nor can we arbitrate whether or not the user actually has the right to use the material (*e.g.*, maybe they emailed the author of the blog and received permission). These issues are all addressed during the DMCA process by those qualified to do so.

And it's not just moderators who won't act upon informal claims of copyright. The company *cannot* act on copyright claims that lack a proper DMCA request without jeopardizing their ["safe harbor" protections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act#Title_II:_Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act).

Of course, the guidance in the Help Center and elsewhere that we *prefer* answers on Stack Overflow to be original contributions still holds. However, it's just guidance, not a requirement. The penalty for failing to contribute original content is not deletion, unless that content has no value whatsoever to the community. But the only thing *worse* from my perspective than unoriginal content (remixed or otherwise) is unoriginal content *without attribution*.

Several people are finding new sources of language to quote back to me that say something of the form, "we prefer that your contributions be original". Yes, we do. That's accurate. It is not, however, evidence of a policy that contradicts anything in this answer. As I noted in [a comment on the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404102/when-should-answers-consisting-entirely-of-cited-copied-content-be-flagged#comment816923_404102):

> As with our homework policy, this is another case of confusing guidance/recommendations offered on Meta sites with prohibitions/policy. We *strongly recommend* that users explain things in their own words and submit original content. However, we do not enforce that with deletion or other sanctions.

I also keep seeing the word "plagiarism" mentioned in comments and in proposed "related questions". Those are all irrelevant to this discussion. The situation that Ryan M brought up, motivating this question, was *not* a case of plagiarism. Plagiarism involves taking credit (or attempting to take credit) for the work of someone else. With attribution incorporated, it's not plagiarism. So this is an entirely separate case. Moderators *do* enforce and sanction violations involving plagiarism; we do *not* enforce off-site licensing agreements.

Comment: That just doesn't address why it's fine to **only** copy stuff from another page without adding anything oneself. It believe that's what the Question here is asking about.

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, @Scratte; the purpose is to answer questions that are asked. Something *is* being added; the content is being referenced in answer to a specific, practical programming question. What would be the alternative? Posting a link-only answer? No, we don't do that. Sometimes, there just isn't anything more that needs to be said, aside from what appears in the documentation or what has already been clearly explained in a blog post on the subject.

Comment: I downvoted partway through reading based on what I could gather from a skim, and then continued to read the rest of the answer in depth, and stand by the downvote. While the answer is a good answer, and covers all the bases, I simply *disagree* with the verdict and think that the flag was absolutely correct. Not on any copyright basis or due to it not being fair use, but because it is unhelpful as an answer and better suited to a *comment*. I don't consider slapping a link on a post to be "good-faith" nor fair use and would be happy with it's removal. Perhaps a CW answer, but not this.

Comment: The alternative being explaining how it works? Or how it works on that particular Question? How the code is to be used? I'm not sure how that code works without going to the linked site, but perhaps that's just me.

Comment: Those are low-quality answer concerns, @Scratte, exactly the same as if it were wholly original work that produced a code-only answer. These are properly addressed with a *downvote*, not a moderator flag. We do not delete answers merely because they contain code with no explanation.

Comment: In this particular case I think the flag was rightly declined; as Cody stated, the answer does a good job of attributing the answer's code right at the beginning. If the poster isn't skilled enough to--or willing to put in the effort to--explain the code, that is perhaps cause for a downvote, but not a flag. I agree it would be ideal if such wholesale copy answers were posted as CW, but that's not required by site policy (though I would love if it *were*).

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, in a [not so old answer to one of my meta-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403133/681538) you wrote that the question on topic did not provide proper attribution and should be regarded as plagiarism, which I from your answer and others comments could only interpret as the problem was that it only was copied material and a link. Now you are saying that it's perfectly fine to just copy and attribute without adding your own content? What am I missing?

Comment: @Alex Not sure where you are confused. What I told you there was, "It is only fine to do this if you provide [proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). That answer didn't." Dumping a "source" down at the bottom isn't attribution. There are specific instructions given in the linked Help Center article about how attribution is supposed to be done. The case Ryan M brought up *isn't plagiarism*, because attribution is provided.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm confused because I don't see the difference. So dumping a link on top of the answer is proper attribution but dumping it in the bottom is plagiarism?

Comment: @CodyGray Oh wait, is it about the name of the author? Even if the name is present in the link?

Comment: But [a moderator message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism/269319#269319) contained: *"It has come to our attention that several of your answers consisted primarily or entirely of text copied from other answers or websites. We prefer not to simply copy content already available elsewhere in lieu of creating something that adds value to this site specifically."*

Comment: @Peter - We are looking for more out of answers than a landing page for links.  Quota and Yahoo Answers allow those types of answers. We strive for something substantial.  Plagiarism is one thing I cannot stand, once a user does it once, sadly it’s common to have happen more than once (I report every instance of plagiarism to a moderator).