# Are "quote-only" answers allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, attribution, blockquote

Are answers that only include (formatted) citations from other sources *allowed* on Stack Overflow?

For example, can I write that *"I found the following explanation from source X to be helpful"* and then proceed to quote the explanation?

Comment: Please bear in mind that not all the questions should be answered.  Ref. [answer]. If the question is not a good fit, IMHO the quote should be added as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Note that an "I found the following explanation from source X *to be helpful*" *should* be followed by something that actually addresses the question. If it just quotes something that may potentially get one past the first step of solving the question, that's likely to be seen as not useful in general. Ideally, you should be able to say "I found the following explanation from source X *to answer this question*" directly.

Comment: The canonical is *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299)*. Related: *[When should answers consisting entirely of cited, copied content be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404102)*

Comment: Note: better save some time and go directly for "Will quote-only answers be well-received?". It'd be a shame if someone tells you "yes that is allowed", you proceed to do it and then see downvotes trickling in. There remains a difference between what is allowed and what is liked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, provided that you follow our [attribution requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)—which consist of clearly indicating all copied content, including the name of the original author (if available), and linking to the original source—such answers are *allowed*. (If you don't follow all of the attribution requirements, then such answers are essentially plagiarism and are therefore not allowed.)

However, as it says in the above-linked Help Center article, such answers are *discouraged*. We *prefer* answers to be your own original work, contributing something new to this site specifically, not just copying something entirely from somewhere else.

If you post such "quote-only" answers on rare occasion, because a complete answer already exists somewhere else, then it is surely not a problem and just helps to make our knowledge base more complete. If you become akin to a bot that merely copies content from elsewhere, that's problematic.

Note that even if you find the complete answer somewhere else that can be copied (with proper attribution), surely there is still *something* you can add on top of it, whether it's a more direct tie-in to the question that was asked, or some code demonstrating its use, or even just a description of your own relevant experiences.

Comment: Also worth noting that the attribution requirements require that you quote _only the relevant portion_.  If you're quoting an _entire offsite article_, that's too much, and you need to trim down what you're quoting.

Comment: After the 1st word this is an unhelpful obfuscated equivocation.

Answer (score 7):

What value do you really add by *just* quoting someone?  Why not showcase what it was that they did in such a way that a user who sees this could more readily apply it so that they gain value?

I would not say that *just* quoting someone would be acceptable as a good answer.

Comment: I think it could help someone to whom the other answers weren't as understandable. I'm asking this question because as I was reading answers on a given post, I couldn't come out with a clear understanding. Nonetheless, when I read this others source, things suddenly *"clicked"*.

Comment: If the answer isn't as understandable, then why are you not using the other content to help support your own answer instead, @MehdiCharife ?

Answer (score 5):

> can I write that "I found the following explanation from source X to be helpful" and then proceed to quote the explanation?

There are many ways to contextualize quotes. Please consider some or all of these:

Why was the quote helpful for you? Why do you expect it to be helpful for OP?

How does the quote apply? Does it directly engage with the question? Does it clear up a misconception underlying the question? Does it explain how to think about the problem? Something else?

Why did you choose this quote, rather than anything else on the same page?

What are you trying to get at with this wording?

How does the explanation apply to OP's circumstance? If the technique, workaround etc. described is applied to the OP's MRE, what does the result look like?

What are the most important aspects of the quote? (After trimming the quote appropriately and formatting it to look more like the original page, consider adding your own formatting for emphasis, and explain which emphasis is yours.)

Comment: Yes, that is a good checklist. Unfortunately, the precedent is not good. Many very highly upvoted answers are nothing but a (too) ***long*** quote and a link, not even with an indication of which part of the long quote is most relevant for the question. (I will collect some samples...)