# When and how should code-only answers copied directly from external sites be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

Earlier today a question was answered with a code-dump and no explanation or exposition. The code had been copied directly from an external site, without any comment or attribution. The answerer had posted a comment under the main question with a link to the code, which is how I found that the answer had been copied. I flagged the question with a custom moderator flag:

> This answer is not only a simple code dump, but it is copied and pasted directly from a solution posted on an external site without attribution.

I also posted a comment under the answer about this being a code-dump without explanation or attribution, and that it was not the answerer's code, but had been copied from an external site.

The answerer responded quickly, saying that it was in fact their code, and that the link was to the answerer's blog. I was in the process of writing a comment to apologize for suggesting that they had posted someone else's code, when the answer (which had 5 downvotes) was removed. Shortly after that, the question was also removed. I was considering retracting the flag, but the answer was removed too quickly, and the flag still seemed to apply given that the answer provided no attribution or context for the copied code.

My flag was declined, with the reason:

> That blog is by the same author.

It was not at all obvious, to me at least, that the blog belonged to the answerer until they stated this in the comments. But even granting that the answerer was posting their own code, I thought that posting any content copied from an external site without attribution is cause for a flag, and in this case since there was no context, but only the copied code, it seemed like an obvious flag.

Answers which are obvious plagiarism should be flagged. But should answers which consist solely of code copied from an external site be flagged? I was under the impression that there is an unwritten rule that any material copied from any external site must be attributed. Did I flag incorrectly, or was I wrong altogether in flagging this question?

Comment: Related, worth reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/353919

Comment: see also: [What does Stack Overflow mean by plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299918/839601)

Comment: Why would an author have to cite their own work in order to reproduce it? The whole point of copyright is so that the author has sole right to reproduce it.

Comment: Re my comment above, it is in response to *"I was under the impression that there is an unwritten rule that any material copied from any external site must be attributed."*. As to your flag, it was reasonable. I would have marked your flag as helpful. Although, whenever I smell plagiarism I always try to determine if the OP was the author of the original. That's part of the flag-as-plagiarism workflow.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this particular declined flag is an indication of wrong action, but rather acknowledgement that this was resolved in opposite way than flag suggested.

I would also flag such answer, the only extra step possibly I'd consider is to check author's profile for blog link. Even than I'd expect clear "you can find more details in *my blog* at ...".

Note that according to big meta's link [found](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359364/when-and-how-should-code-only-answers-copied-directly-from-external-sites-be-fla/359365#comment532136_359364) by abccd: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) editing post with link's source would be preferred action.

Comment: This is one of the fundamental concerns I have had about flags - that helpful or declined status depends on the *final action taken* rather than whether the flag alerted the mod or the community to something that *needed to be researched or investigated*. Imagine if scientists were given "rejected article" statuses (and subjected to publication bans, exclusion from faculty positions, etc.) for having negative research results. "You can't publish any more articles on cancer until 2020 because your last five articles were all about experimental treatments that *don't* work!"