# How should I handle answers that were wrong and then edited to show another person's answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

#### When your answer is wrong...

... you copy/paste correct answer, add "My initial answer was wrong" and credits, [voila](https://www.google.com/search?q=voila+meaning)!

Yes?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3390424/1997232) is such an answer. I have a strong feeling to downvote and flag it, but I am not sure. How should I handle this?

Comment: The comments need to be zapped first to allow a meaningful edit to the answer.  Having a wrong solution accepted as the answer can be quite a pita, mods rarely help getting it deleted.  You can DV it, kinda pointless on a correct answer.

Comment: This happened nearly 9 years ago...why are we digging it up? I have seen a lot of older post in the feed today for no good reason then someone just trying to chew up old bones.

Comment: What grinds my gears more is that the answer was edited to be a carbon copy of the answer that was deemed correct if I judge the order of events correctly.

Comment: @Gimby yes that is correct, Wallace came and edited his answer 5 years after STO posted the answer to provide the same duplicated text

Comment: I assume that the author of the answer realized his answer was wrong, and since he probably couldn't delete his accepted answer, he tried to fix it by replacing it with the contents of a correct answer.

Comment: @CoderJoe, I think it's a very.. hmm.. brave form of plagiarism, that's why I am c̶a̶l̶l̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶p̶o̶l̶i̶c̶e̶  asking here.

Comment: Not saying your wrong I think your right @Sinatr its just odd seeing so many old post this morning

Comment: Comments like these do explain why there's such a shortage of answerers and why so many of the remaining ones answer questions in comments.  Do stop downvoting correct answers, that is just hostile.  Attribution was adequate, there wasn't anything else he could do.  Go easy on your friendly SO users, you may need them some day.

Comment: Would you rather have the accepted answer stay incorrect? As the accepted answer it can't be deleted so updating at and attributing it sure seems like the best route.

Comment: @HansPassant, but you said I can downvote. As for "anything else to do" : I'd keep old "wrong" answer untouched. If accepted answer doesn't works than what people do? They try another one.

Comment: @CoderJoe 2019 - 2015 = 9?

Comment: The accepted answer is now correct and it used to be wrong. Hard to argue that is a bad thing.

Comment: @tom I was definitly looking at the wrong answer there was a post from 2010 in the feed and I was looking at that when I made the comment

Comment: That leads to question why did the OP accept the answer in the first place if it was wrong? should a user really change an answer if it was accepted? Accordingly what he posted may have worked for the OP @Gimby

Comment: I would agree with CoderJoe's comment regarding the fact that the answer was accepted. So even if the answer doesn't work, I would keep that, explain why and how it doesn't work (anymore?) and then link or _quote_ the correct answer, together with credits ofc.

Comment: I didn't object to you using your votes as you please, I objected against a bunch of meta visitors voting for no real good reason but to get-the-sonofabitch, it seems.  I say my daily prayer, wishing one of my post won't be the subject of a meta question or an audit.  So far it is working, rabbit's foot, four clover leaf and live lady bugs to cover all cases.

Comment: @HansPassant, as we started talking about downvotes, which remove reputation.. even with ~150 more downvotes "sonofabitch" still *gaining* reputation for copy/pasting someone else answer. My aim is actually netting him exactly 0 (when answer is deleted somehow). Official rollback will also do (not sure though). Or should the answer rather stay and teach others (me?) how you earn reputation?

Comment: @sinatr only 33 of the upvotes came after the edit. The rest came before.

Comment: wonder if it would look better if answer was made community wiki after the edit. I myself [tend to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A839601+is%3Aa+wiki%3Ayes) when it feels like I have to borrow too much from somewhere else (happens quite regularly in cross-site meta duplicates)

Comment: The user did pretty much the best they could. They can't delete their answer, it's accepted. It's wrong, so they don't want to leave it, and it's accepted, so it's always going to show up first. move on. (i agree, CW probably would have been a good idea)

Comment: I contest that the user did "pretty much the best they could". The best would be to leave the original content, explain why it doesn't suffice (possibly with an indication of why it would appear at first glance to be the appropriate solution), and also indicate that the other user's answer is actually correct. Why do we need two copies of the right answer?

Comment: The question has been deleted, can you share a screenshot, please in your question?

Comment: @double-beep how about [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20160319061913/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390358/using-reflection-how-do-i-detect-properties-that-have-setters/3390424) mirror of the question from 2016?

Comment: @CoderJoe Answer accepted state is pretty insignificant, especially years after the fact. It should in no way hinder someone from fixing their answer. Especially that one answer that regardless of vote count just sticks to the top like a rebel without a cause...

Comment: @HansPassant *"there wasn't anything else he could do"* - sure there was. He could've deleted his answer, if he believed it was useless or outright harmful. Or he could've done nothing at all, and let voters indicate which answer they prefer. Either of these would've been better than copying and pasting another answer from the same page into his.

Comment: @MarkAmery Technically they'd have to flag their own answer requesting deletion, they couldn't delete it on their own, but the end result would be the same, as a mod would honor such a request as long as they explain why they want it deleted.

Comment: @Servy Ah, good catch - I wasn't aware that the green tick doesn't show up on deleted accepted answers, and so wrongly thought by inspection that the answer had never been accepted. But yeah, a mod flag for deletion in that situation is the right thing to do. (Really, the system should simply allow deletion of accepted answers like any other answer. Not permitting it is a pretty arbitrary restriction.)

Comment: @MarkAmery The reason it's prevented is to prevent people from vandalizing their own content when they decide to leave.  Personally rather than preventing self deletion, I'd prefer an attempt to delete to instead automatically flag for mod attention stating that a user is requesting their own accepted answer be deleted, because not everyone knows that mods will honer sincere requests in that situation.

Comment: @Servy *"to prevent people from vandalizing their own content when they decide to leave"* - right, but specifically restricting that to *deletions* of *accepted* answers is arbitrary. If I can still delete all my non-accepted answers and edit the accepted ones into giant ASCII cocks, does the fact that I cannot *technically* delete the accepted answers really protect the site much, or indeed at all?

Comment: @MarkAmery You can only delete 5 non-accepted answers a day, and doing so triggers a mod flag for them to investigate possible vandalism.  And the theory is that accepted answers are less likely to actually be bad answers actually meriting deletion than a non-accepted answer.  I suppose you could argue for adding the same protection to posts above a certain score, under the same logic.

Comment: Copying and pasting of another already existing answer is never a useful thing. Linking to one is though.

Comment: @Gimby The point I was making is the OP accepted his original answer...his edit was completely different and another user had posted a "better" answer. If he wanted to fix his answer he should have edited the question and added details explaining why he was wrong and what the correct answer is and why instead of directly copying someone else answer

Comment: @CoderJoe that would have been excellent remarks to make all those years ago when it happened, by at this point it is a case for captain hindsight ;) It doesn't help to dwell on how things should have been handled back then (I'll just let my gears grind on), all we should care about today is what we do about it now. Which boils down to: don't make it worse. Doing nothing would have worked, but I think Brad made the right call to just delete it. The only thing lost like tears in the rain, is a single acceptance checkmark.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In response to multiple flags originating from this Meta question, I decided to delete the accepted answer. I usually don't delete incorrect accepted answers, but I make exceptions in the cases where the answerer themself requests deletion or where the answer content has been removed or severely edited by the answerer because they recognized it was wrong.

Answerers cannot delete accepted answers, but they normally would be able to retract their own wrong answers. I'm sympathetic to this in the case of accepted answers, and I nearly always delete wrong accepted answers at the request of the answerer. I see redacting an answer or completely redirecting it to another answer as being a similar case, so if someone flags these I tend to remove them as long as no information would be lost.

Given that this is identical to the other answer there, I saw no harm in removing this to make way for the answer they admitted was correct.

Comment: As the answer is now deleted is it worth keeping this thread alive?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Yes.  Someone may want to propose a different course of action be taken (this, like most actions, is reversible), and it also serves to inform others about what to do if they find themselves in a similar situation.

Comment: @Servy Hmm... I see...

Comment: As the author of the now deleted answer pointed out that the answer provided by STO was correct, wouldn't it make sense to mark this answer as solution? Only in case this is something a moderator may do.

Comment: @SaschaM78 We don't have a way to mark answers as correct, votes do the talking there. You are probably talking about the accepted checkmark which only the question author can apply to one answer, that is something different.

Comment: @Gimby thank you and yes, I was talking about the checkmark instead of using upvotes. But when looking at the question again I see that no moderator could checkmark an answer for the author as there may be several answers that may be the solution for the question author (in the case of the referenced question one answer containing the correct code was posted without explanation one minute before STO's version so there is no way to tell which one would have been picked by the question author). Sorry for taking this a bit OT.

Answer (score 12):

#### Flag this answer with request for deletion.

I have raised a custom flag with the message

> I think this answer needs to be deleted due to the author admitting it was incorrect and redirecting users to another answer.

and it was marked helpful. Hope this is normal practice dealing with answers that can't be deleted by a user due to being accepted.

I'm sure such answers don't add any value to the site.

Answer (score -11):

### Should we allow this?

The answer is simply no, The OP accepted the answer before it was edited to reflect the other users. That means the original answer either worked for the OP or was at the very least helpful to the OP.

### What would happen today

Think about this as a mod

If today an answer was posted and accepted and then the answerer realizes that someone had a better answer then them and they copied their answer(while still giving them credit) the answer would still get flagged as "not an answer" and would be deleted or at the very least rolled back to the original

So weather its today or 5 years ago it does not matter we can't judge the question based on technical correctness, judge it for what it is...a direct copy of a better answer on the page

### What should we do at this point?

I would suggest reverting the answer to the original with a note underneath stating that the answer is outdated to see the other answer instead.

Comment: What would we gain with this?

Comment: Removal of plagiarism, for one. A rollback to an un-plagiarized version should be the first order of business.

Comment: Better to properly credit the source, instead of having an accepted answer that it’s apparently wrong.

Comment: Plagiarization requires the source to be unattributed, @Roddy.  That answer looks pretty attributed to me.

Comment: @yivi But the point is the OP accepted the original answer he didnt accept the edited version

Comment: I'm looking at this through the eyes of a mod repeating the statement "mods do not judge based on technical correctness"

Comment: @fbueckert - There is a point where attribution is not sufficient. I can summarize a newspaper article and provide attribution ("according to the New York Times article 'XYZ', {some claim}"), but if I copy-paste the full text of the article including the attribution, they're still going to come after me. Perhaps here it's not plagiarism, but it's definitely not fair to the user whose answer was duplicated.

Comment: That's a better argument, @Roddy.  It certainly isn't plagiarism, so that line isn't really constructive to use.

Comment: @fbueckert - At my university this was still identified as plagiarism. But possibly it just falls under ['appropriation'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appropriation_(art)).

Comment: @fbueckert No, plagiarism *doesn't* require the source to be unattributed.  Attributing a source while using the entirety of their work and adding nothing original is still plagiarism.  It's appropriate when *using another's work to augment your own*, rather than simply copying someone else's work in entirety without addition.

Comment: @Servy The definition of plagiarism is "the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work". Emphasis on "representation of them as one's OWN ORIGINAL WORK".

Comment: @dtasev You have a source for that definition?  A significant majority of definitions I've seen (including SE's own definition, most relevantly) state that using others' work as the entirety of one's own contribution, rather than using the work of others to supplement one's own original work is also plagiarism, even if the work is cited.

Comment: You folks realise arguing over the term used to describe the action doesn't actually bring you that much closer to a solution right? Call it plagiarism, call it copywrite theft, call it stealing, call it an answer heist, it doesn't matter; the issue is with the act itself and whether it is the right or wrong course of action, not the tem used to describe it.

Comment: @Servy I struggle to find a source that is NOT that definition. SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299918/2823526, OED: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plagiarism, Merriam-Webster: https://www.mtsu.edu/graduate/pdf/Plagiarism.pdf, Oxford University: https://www.ox.ac.uk/students/academic/guidance/skills/plagiarism?wssl=1. In University assignments you may be flagged for plagiarism if you quote something, but as long as you make it clear it is a quote and reference it, you will not be punished.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland What? We're not arguing over the term, we're arguing over whether the action is PLAGIARISM or NOT.

Comment: @Servy Obviously, if you submit a piece of 'work' that is entirely a quote with reference to other work, then you have done nothing, and I don't see how this "nothing" can be counted as plagiarism, unless you do not reference the original source.

Comment: @dtasev [SO's definition of plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says, "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own." The second source is a single sentence, and isn't specific enough to determine what it does or doesn't include. The mtsu source states it's a summary, and to see https://www.plagiarism.org/ for more information, which states, "copying so many words or ideas from a source that it makes up the majority of your work, whether you give credit or not" https://www.plagiarism.org/article/what-is-plagiarism

Comment: @Servy Agreed. I was incorrect.

Answer (score -14):

#### Nothing should be done on this answer

It seems that the accepted answer is currently correct, and that the author has properly attributed his source of the (updated) answer. Everything is working as intended.

> I have strong feeling to downvote and flag it

You should absolutely not flag the answer. It was posted in good faith, and it answers the question with proper attribution. There is nothing a moderator should do about it.

About downvoting, nobody can stop you from doing it, but what would be the point? If the answer is correct it should be upvoted. This is true regardless if the previous version was not the best, we vote on the current version of the answer, not the previous versions.

Comment: I would have mod flagged this, solely because the OP of the answer himself said it was wrong, I'd rather see it mod deleted than to have the OP vandalize it or just plagiarize instead

Comment: perhaps you missed the part about it being plagerised, but you know the answer was changed, not improved. changing the answer is reason to flag or roll back anyway.

Comment: OP accepting the answer doesn't even mean it works for them. That should be the case, but I've seen several cases like that.