# How to deal with answers that copy solution from newer answers

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

Take this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34179116/1974224) - the answer is a valid one, however there's a [newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36579682/1974224) that provided this solution before the older one did. Basically, looking at the revision history this is what happened:

1. answer A was posted saying that there's no support for the asked problem
2. answer B is posted, and gives a solution
3. answer B gets updated with a definitive solution
4. answer A gets updated, copies the solution from answer B, and removes the original content

What the author of answer A did doesn't feel right to me, my question is if this is something that should be flagged?

Comment: I see the chain of events differently: 1. Answer A gets posted saying it's not supported. 2. Support gets implemented. 3. Answer B is posted, and says support just got implemented. 4. Answer A gets updated to reflect it's now supported. The code involved is one line, and that line is stated in the docs. It's hardly plagiarism, just making sure the top answer is correct. If there are substantial chunks of code involved, it's different, but I don't see a problem here. Better to update the top answer than to have an invalid top answer that can't be deleted

Comment: @ErikA I also didn't felt that this is literally plagiarism, however we now have two answers which give the same solution, but the newer one is better because it provides more details. At least the older answer should provide attribution, IMO.

Comment: Yup, and that's properly reflected in votes here. Altogether, SO working like it should, except the age-old problem that the accepted answer is stuck at the top position.

Comment: Or even better, the original answer could've been kept, but a disclaimer added: "This answer is no longer valid, see B's answer"

Comment: @Cristik or answer got comment like "This is worst answer ever. The feature X is implemented for whole 3 days already and this @#$@ did not care to fix answer. Can't stand this site populated by @#$#" - positive way to react would be to update the answer and mark comment as "no longer needed" (especially if answer can't be deleted)... and then maybe check if there are updated answers and upvote them as necessary.

Comment: Had this situation happen to me in a very blatant way. I confronted the person, got dismissed rudely, flagged and got declined. Not too much you could do unless it is undisputed plagiarism.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know we can flag answers with "plagiarism". I had such situation in the past, but didn't do something other than add sarcastic comment (which was ignored).

Comment: @Cristik, as a reader, having to read an answer only to find it redirects me to another answer (which, keep in mind, could be edited or deleted at any time without OP being notified) isn't _better_ than having the pertinent information available in the first answer I read.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384972/1997232). Such cases are complex, but I am totally against editing someone else work into accepted answer. Either delete it (ask moderator to delete own post) or maybe make a little remark "my answer is wrong see another one" period. Don't steal other answerer upvotes (making answer community wiki may looks honest at first, but it's also bad).

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland agreed, but nonetheless a disclaimer that the solution was first provided into the other answer, could've been added. Duplicate information is something we try to avoid on SO. Also, no longer valid answers are good for historical purposes, so the original content could've been kept.

Comment: I agree there. I don't like answers in comments (even in Meta) but to show we are on the same wave length; - I'd like to see: the new info, the original answer, a shout out to any answers that beat him to the punch (if even only as a 'cap doff' if not full attribution).

Comment: @Styx You can't blanket flag such answers as plagiarism (or rather, you can, the flag will just be declined). Plagiarism is the act of copying content with the intent to pass it off as your own, e.g. without proper attribution. If Answer A is edited to add the content from Answer B and says "as Answer B says"... that's clearly attributing the content to Answer B and thus not plagiarism. Please be judicious with such flags.

Comment: @TylerH I'm sorry, I was referring to my situation, when Answer A was edited with content from Answer B [my answer, accepted] in such blatant way that my flag of plagiarism (flagged yesterday) was accepted :)

Answer (score 34):

Normally the answer is "Mod flag plagiarism". And, the order of operations here seems to suggest that might be what happened. There's two caveats to this, however

## The answer is irreducible

> swift package generate-xcodeproj

That's the answer to the question. Period. There's nothing more to add or subtract. If people are wholesale copying blocks of code, flag that every time. But when the answer is irreducible like this, copying is a bit harder to prove. How do we know the OP didn't stumble across this elsewhere, only to come back and find someone beat him to it?

Mind you, newer answers should add something new in cases like this. I can't stand the "Me too" answers that copy stuff like this (when they're made months or years later), but that's not what happened here.

## The answer is accepted

You can't delete your own answer once it's accepted. And in this case, the OP did what I would prefer here: he made his "No you can't do that" into a "Yes you can". In other words **he made the accepted answer the correct one**. Considering my previous point, this is helpful to future users. More importantly, it doesn't try to upstage the later answer that gave the same thing. As such, the later (correct) answer has gotten more upvotes.

For better or worse, that's how the OP seems to want it. I'm hesitant to delete or even downvote the accepted answer as a result.

Comment: It's good etiquette to cite the other answer when updating your own with content that matches theirs, though. This is similar to deferring to existing academic literature for ideas that have already been published, even if you weren't aware of the specific papers when the idea came to your attention. If I were updating an accepted answer with drastic changes someone else had posted, I would probably community wiki the post.

Comment: If one has an accepted answer that they believe is wrong, they can simply flag it and a mod will delete it, as long as it's clear it's not vandalism.  There's no need to plagiarize another answer just because you realize your answer is wrong, nor does that excuse plagiarism.

Comment: Your analysis does not match the [timeline of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34179116/timeline). The accept vote was only cast in 2019-04-23, almost three years after the edit.

Comment: Lightness' edit seems to resolve the situation into an ideal outcome. The accepted answer shows both original and updated solutions and provides (some) attribution as best as possible without an under-oath attestation by the accepted answerer as to the source of their updated solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you believe an answer has plagiarized another answer then flag the post and explain why you think so.  In cases like this where there is lots of editing at relevant times, it's important that you include such non-obvious information when flagging to ensure the person handling the flag notices.

Comment: This was my initial feeling, some kind of plagiarism, however as the updated answer consists in mainly a shell command, wasn't sure if it should be so harshly treated.

Comment: @Cristik Maybe it will be maybe it won't be.  Either way, if you think it was plagiarized, all you can do is flag it.  The mod may or may not agree.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't like declined flags :P

Comment: "Yeah, but I don't like declined flags"  - So pretend that you didn't see the problem in the first place :P

Answer (score 6):

If someone visits a question in the future then it would be definitely okay to find the correct answer as the accepted one. The truth is solutions in tech cannot be completely invariable, there's always a high likelihood that a better solution will be implemented in the future and thus I think it would be definitely okay to update the answer. The thing about plagiarism as I would view it is quite hard to hold because most visitors **tend to try the accepted answer first** before moving on to other lower ranked answers.

Comment: *"a better solution will be implemented in the future"* - this is why better answers appears and receive more upvotes than old accepted ones ([my experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753848/1997232)). The green checkmark shouldn't be used blindly, without checking date of post/edit, comments, etc. Yes, we want nice looking Q&A, but not at such a cost when original authors suffer from plagiarism. Imagine that happens to you: you will spend time digging an answer and someone who said earlier "no, that's not possible" will copy/paste your work into his answer. How is that "definitely ok"?

Answer (score 4):

The full timelines of the answers include extra information relevant for assessing some of the claims being made in this discussion. In summary:

- Dec 9 '15 at 12:42 -- *Answer A* ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34179116/timeline)) is posted, saying there is no ready-made solution.
- Apr 12 '16 at 17:01 -- *Answer B* ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36579682/timeline)) is posted, pointing out a newly available solution.

  - Answer A score at the time: 1
- Jul 22 '16 -- Answer A is downvoted, possibly due to not including the new solution.

  - Answer A score: 0
  - Answer B score: 5
- Jul 25 '16 at 15:16 -- Answer A is edited to incorporate the same solution featured in answer B.

  - Answer A score: 0
  - Answer B score: 5
- Apr 23 '19 at 18:57 -- Answer A is accepted. (Note that, while unaccept events are not recorded in the timeline, [in most cases they show up in the reputation history of the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144127/242059). Looking at the latter shows no unaccepts on that particular answer, so it is very likely this was the first accept vote cast on it.)

  - Answer A score: 10
  - Answer B score: 27

Before continuing, let's get one matter out of the way: *plagiarism is way too strong a charge for this situation*. There is hardly any original content at play ([as Erik A puts it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386908/how-to-deal-with-answers-that-copy-solution-from-newer-answers?cb=1#comment709570_386908), "the code involved is one line, and that line is stated in the docs"), and it is entirely plausible that the answer A author knew of the new solution by means other than answer B, and was reminded to update his answer by some other event (say, the Jul 22 '16 downvote).

The absence of plagiarism, however, does not mean the actions by the answer A author were the best possible ones. The timeline analysis above shows that answer A, in all likelihood, was only accepted nearly three years after the edit, and that it never was the top answer scorewise. Since there is no substantial difference between the edited answer A and answer B, the ideal course of action would be deleting answer A upon noticing it was superseded.

(Had answer A been the accepted one at the time of the edit, deleting it would not have been an option, and so editing the new solution would have been reasonable. In such cases, attribution should be included if the edit was based on another answer, though, as discussed above, that might well not have been the case in this concrete case. It is also worth noting that, in such a situation, an alternative approach would be asking the question OP to change the accept vote.)